# MS-VISIO how to create a shape that prompts user to insert hyperlink?

Tags: microsoft-visio, shapes

How to create a shape that prompts the user to insert a hyperlink?

similar to how this shape currently performs.
"Software and Database > Software > Controls > Hyperlink"

Comment: Maybe the official article could help you:[Add data to shapes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-data-to-shapes-09272394-5243-4e1b-bcfa-425a8b4d1ce2?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the shape using the **Shapesheet editor**, in the cell **EventDrop** in the **Events** section add the formula:

=DOCMD(1585)